# Help using signtool.exe in Delphi project post-build events

Tags: delphi, post-build-event

This is a very simple question. What should I write in Delphi post build events to execute a coomand line tool?

I wrote this:

```
c:\BinPath\signtool.exe sign /f c:\BinPath\Mypfxfile.pfx /p MyPassword 
/t http:// timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll c:\BinPath\Project1.exe
```

(where c:\BinPath is the Delphi output path, for simplicity I copied signtool.exe adn pfx file in the same folder)

as i build the project I have this modal window error:

> --------------------------- Project 1- CodeGear Delphi for Microsoft Windows - Form1
>   --------------------------- Cannot open file "C:\SourcePath\EXEC".
>   Impossible to find the specified
>   path..

and in the messages I have

> [Exec Error] EXEC(1):
>   "SignerTimeStamp() failed."
>   (-2147467259/0x80004005)
>
> [Exec Error]
>   exit from command
>   "c:\BinPath\signtool.exe sign /f
>   c:\BinPath\Mypfxfile.pfx /p MyPassword
>   /t http://
>   timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
>   c:\BinPath\Project1.exee" with code 1.

How to manage this? In Delphi help I read (from *Creating Build Events* topic):

*Enter the build commands, one command per line, and press Return after entering each command. Commands consist of any valid DOS command, such as: copy $() c:\Built\$()*

So i simply inserted in the build event what (`c:\BinPath\....Project1.exe`) I was able to run from command prompt. Where is the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could have deleted this question, since I found the problem, but I think it is better to leave it since it can be useful for others:

THE PROBLEM WAS SIMPLY

```
http:// timestamp...
```

of course should be

```
http://timestamp...
```

when copying on build event I inserted an extra space by mistake. By reading the question posted I found the error...

Comment: Asking the question often answers it. +1 in both the Q and the A for not deleting them: these "duh" moments are important, as they happen too all of us every now and then. I'm not ashamed of them (just the other day I called a DLL function that expected a PAnsiChar with a PUnicodeChar - how "duh" is that <g>) and I'm glad others aren't either.

Comment: @vcldeveloper: Stack Overflow tells me that I can accept my own answer in 2 days.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes. We learn by mistakes. Sometimes we need others to tell us about our mistakes, sometimes we just need ourselves, and in this second case I feel at home ("duh" moment, but also "I made it" moment)...